# How to pass a Content Type parameter to an embedded PowerApp

Tags: sitepages, powerapps-canvas, parameter

Trying to work out if this is possible.  I'm on Sharepoint 365 and have a custom content type extending "Site Page" called "Project Page" that has an additional page parameter, "Project ID".  On the page is a canvas PowerApp that hits a database based on a URL parameter to retrieve some info about the project.  Right now I'm hardcoding "...&projectid=123" into each of these pages, however is there a way to somehow insert "...&projectid={Page.ProjectID}" into the PowerApp URL?

Working in a corporate environment so adding additional components or custom-crafting something for Sharepoint is probably out of the question.

Comment: where is this Project ID, is it a custom column in Site Page SP List ?

Comment: No, it's a parameter of the page object itself (i.e. Page Details from the menu bar on a page.)  I have the same information in another list so if that's a possibility that could work.  I just need to determine if there's some way of passing dynamic data to the SharePoint PowerApp component.  2 says of furious searching and forum scanning have suggested this may not be possible however.

Comment: I recommend you explore further the details, I cannot see or understand your business need exactly, I would love to have more information then I will try to help you ☺